# LEFT JOIN to return at most one row for a 1-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query in SQL Server where I'm doing multiple left joins. At one point I get to:

```
...LEFT JOIN foo on a.id = foo.id AND foo.code = 100
```

Up to that join statement in the query, `a.id` is not repeated; there's only 1 row for every `a.id`. But table `a` and `foo` have a 1-to-many relationship, so after that join statement I get multiple rows with the same `a.id`.

Table `foo` will always have multiple records where `foo.id = a.id`, but it may or may not have a record where `foo.id = a.id AND foo.code = 100`. If it does, there will be only 1 such record. So, what I want to see in the final query results is just 1 row for every `a.id`; if `foo` has a record where `f.id = a.id and f.code = 100`, then I want to see the date values from `f.date1` and `f.date2` from that record. If `foo` doesn't have such a record, then I just want to see NULL values for `f.date1` and `f.date2`.

**Edit from the comments**:

It turns out that table `foo` actually can have multiple rows where `a.id = foo.id and foo.code = 100`.

Comment: what are you getting that this doesn't work? it should work based on what you have there.

Comment: maybe do a 

SELECT CASE WHEN foo.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE f.date1 END as date1
along with the left join so when the row doesn't match you get a null date1 and do the same for date2

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your `join` looks ok -- just `select` the fields you need from `foo`...

Comment: The only way I can see this not working, is if your where clause you reference a table on the RIGHT from the left joins thus negating the left join.  So: Select * from A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID where B.Value = 'Blue' would negate the left join.  If you have a where cluase and any values are from the right table ("and include all rows equal to A from B) then you've basically eliminated all the nulls the left join would return.

Comment: Ah, there's my problem - the SQL is correct, but it turns out table foo actually *can* have multiple rows where a.id = foo.id and foo.code = 100. Occam's razor wins again...

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do it is to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    a.id
    ,OA_foo.date1
    ,OA_foo.date2
FROM
    a
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            -- TOP(1)
            foo.date1
            ,foo.date2
        FROM foo
        WHERE
            foo.id = a.id
            AND foo.code = 100
        -- ORDER BY ...
    ) AS OA_foo
;
```

If you know for sure that the filter `foo.id = a.id AND foo.code = 100` will **always** return only one row (or no rows), then you can leave the query as is.

If it is possible that nested query returns more than row and you want to leave only one row, then specify appropriate `ORDER BY` and `TOP(1)`.